# Changing the position of PlotLabels

Tags: labeling

In the image below, the PlotLabels are, in my view, too close together. I am using the code:

```
PlotLabels -> Placed[{" t = 4"}, {Scaled[1], After}]
```

Is there any way to move the labels apart. I am aware of After, Before, Above, and Below. But is there a way to a more nuanced positioning?

[image]

Comment: Put in a line return (`\n`).

Comment: Please give a complete example that we can run ourselves to reproduce the problem.

Comment: .\n did the job.